# Memory-related error: ff package on Windows 2008 server

Tags: r, windows-server-2008, ff

I am trying to do the simplest indexing of an `ff` vector in R v3.1.0, on a Windows 2008 server. The following basic code:

```
x = ff(1:10)
x[ff(2:3)]
```

Returns the error:

```
Error in ffindexget(x, i) : 
cannot allocate memory block of size 67108864 Tb
In addition: Warning message:
In bbatch(length, BATCHBYTES/(recvalbytes + 2 * recindbytes)) :
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Any insights as per how/why could that possibly happen? The code runs perfectly on my local Windows 7 machine, hence am I right to assume the issue is with the operating system? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe your hard disk is full

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I am not sure this is the case. I can upload any object, in their gigabytes. It seems like an indexing function issue at first glance.

Comment: Maybe it is indeed related to your hardware. What are your ff options available in options() ?

Comment: This is what I found, if of any help? `$ffbatchbytes [1] 733992714

$ffcaching [1] "mmnoflush"

$ffdrop [1] TRUE

$ffextension [1] "ff"

$fffinonexit [1] TRUE

$ffmaxbytes [1] 36699635712

$ffpagesize [1] 65536`

Comment: You could try in reducing the ffbatchbytes option. Your error message looks like there was a numeric overflow before the ffindexget. So try out changing ffbatchbytes to something lower than the defaults of your incredible machine. e.g. options(ffbatchbytes = 37570478)

Comment: Tried it, same error unfortunately.

Comment: Have you also tried to change the ffmaxbytes option to something lower (like what is on your Windows 7 machine)? ffindexget has an option BATCHBYTES = getOption("ffmaxbytes"). You could consider decreasing the ffmaxbytes option. FYI, mine is 536870912.